# Sahi Scripts does not work on Internet Explorer and Opera Properly

Tags: webautomation, sahi

I generate some automation script with using Firefox. 
Now i playback the scripts in Firefox. Everything is going rigth but in Opera have some Problem. Also in Internet Explorer same as..

In Internet Explorer, this part of the code is generally shown as Failed after script execution:

```
_popup("csi")._assertExists(_div("deneme"));
_popup("csi")._assertEqual("deneme");  
_getText(_div("deneme"))   //This part is failed.
```

Also in Opera,

`_sahi._popup("csi")._sahi._click(_sahi._link("Bilgi Güncelleme")); //This part is failed.`  Related with Character set ?

Finally, This fail parts are working fine in Firefox. What should i do to fix these problems.

Thanks and BR,

Answer (score 0):

```
_popup("csi")._assertEqual("deneme");  
_getText(_div("deneme"))
```

looks incorrect. It should be

```
_popup("csi")._assertEqual("deneme", _getText(_div("deneme"));
```

Have you checked on the Controller what _link("Bilgi Güncelleme") shows up as on Opera?
You could also try with _link("/Bilgi/") to check if the error is due to the special character.

Comment: Thanks Narayan,  i'll check my code on Monday then reply back to you. Thanks ;)